# Powershell command to check count of characters between random 2 words in a pdf file

Tags: powershell, count, character

I am trying to find out PowerShell command to check count of characters between 2 random words in a file.

Script below gives count of total characters in a file. However I am lookin for count where I mention 2 random words in file and count characters:

```
dir -Include *.* -Recurse | % { 
  $_ | select name, 
    @{n="characters";e={get-content $_ | measure-object -character | select -expa characters }} , 
    @{n="words";     e={get-content $_ | measure-object -word      | select -expa words }} , 
    @{n="lines";     e={get-content $_ | measure-object -line      | select -expa lines }}
} | 
ft -AutoSize
```

Comment: Do you want to pick words and search for those, or just pick any random "word"? What should happen if there are multiple instances of either word?

Comment: You can't just use ```Get-Content``` on a pdf (based on the question title) to get the text - it's a binary format and the characters that get displayed on-screen in a reader don't necessarily appear in the same sequence in the file. You'll need to use a library that can parse a pdf and extract the text from it first, and then process that...

Comment: @Cpt.Whale Yes I will manually select 2 unique words in document but would like to know number of characters within these 2 words..

Answer (score 0):

Here's an example file `test.txt`

```text
hello world example
this is sample text
```

you could try something like this:

```
$firstWord = "world"
$lastWord  = "sample"

# in keeping with your example:
@{n="charBetween";e={
  # Get raw content for a single string instead of per-line
  $text = Get-Content $_ -Raw

  # index of first and last words
  $i1 = $text.IndexOf($firstWord) + $firstWord.Length  
  $i2 = $text.IndexOf($lastWord) - 1

  # return -1 if one of the words was not found
  if ($i1,$i2 -eq -1) { return -1 }

  # output count each character between words
  else { $text[$i1..$i2].Count }
}}


# returns like this:

charBetween
-----------
18
```

Be aware that `Get-Content -Raw` contains newline characters, so the count will be slightly higher if including multiple lines.